# How do I add the NULL device to Windows XP Embedded?

Tags: windows, windows-xp-embedded

Windows XP Embedded is missing the NULL or "NUL" device.  For one thing, Visual Studio seems to require it and trying to build a project aborts with a PRJ0015 error.

Anyone know how to configure an XPe image to include support for the NUL device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Null Device Driver" is available in the XPe Target Designer, but it's normally hidden. Apparently each component has a visibility level, and if it's lower than that set in the Target Designer options (Tools->Options), it's hidden. Null Device Driver is at level 200, so I set the level to 100 and could see it and install it.

Answer (score 2):

There's another important situation where you're going to want the NUL device: if you're installing some or all of the Cygwin UNIX solutions for Windows.  In particular, if you're doing something like, oh, I don't know, to pick a completely random example, trying to put an SSH server on the damned thing so you can, just on a lark, say, log in and maintain it.

That's right-- Cygwin actually maps its UNIX /dev/null device to the Windows NUL device.  You know, for maximum compatibility.  Just in case the platform-specific implementation of IMMEDIATELY THROWING DATA INTO THE TOILET AND OBLITERATING IT, NEVER TO BE SEEN AGAIN, UNTIL THE HEAT DEATH OF THE UNIVERSE, happened to be novel and innovative.

While cygwin will INSTALL without NUL available, it will not, in fact, actually enjoy a typical work day.  This is most evident the first time you try to launch a bash shell, and notice a slew of error messages about /dev/null resulting in no such file or directory errors.  One presumes the device is perhaps actually just an NTFS link, but who knows.

In any case, the fix is to add the "Null Device Driver" component, helpfully located under Software -> System -> Other, a surprisingly small category which also contains such useful components as Internet Checkers, the Schedule Service Command Line Utility, the 1394 Kernel Debugger Support Library, EBCDIC support for Microsoft Bob, some cheat codes for Zork, and the code pages to say "(A)bort, (R)etry, (I)gnore, (F)ail?" in Muppet Swedish ("(B)ork, b(o)rk, bo(r)k, bor(k)?")

Hope this helps,
   Matt "Breakpoint" Heck

Answer (score 0):

Running Visual Studio itself on XP Embedded doesn't seem like it'd be supported.  You should build on a full OS and then just deploy your application to XP embedded.